# Добавление контента

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте, подскажите как сделать что бы после запроса ajax контент который приходит, не заменял уже существующий, а добавлялся. Приведу пример:

был такой html код:
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>

после запроса ajax:
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>Я только что под грузился с помощью ajax</div>
<div>3</div>

Comment: спасибо after то что нужно))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для подобного можно использовать [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) и [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('div').eq(1).after('<div>Я только что под грузился с помощью ajax</div>');
```